# UITableViewCell error loading UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

[image: Screen capture]

[image: Screen capture]

As you can see there is an error. I'm loading a UIWebView on each UITableViewCell. The problem is that when it loads a large amount of data the UITableViewCell disappears and when I scroll the text overlay itself.

Maybe there is a max height for a UITableViewCell?

It's another error?

What can I do?

**Edit:** this is the viewController code that manages the API response and store each 'post' as a UIWebView, wich is loaded in the main view and the UITableViewCell contentView. The question is: where is the problem with large webViews? code? max height? memory?

```
#import "TopicViewController.h"
#import "HTMLController.h"

NSString *_topicID;

@implementation TopicViewController

@synthesize heightForView = _heightForView;
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize htmlController = _htmlController;
@synthesize pageCounter = _pageCounter;

+ (void)setTopicID:(NSString *)topicID {
    _topicID = topicID;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{    
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.heightForView = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    self.htmlController = [[HTMLController alloc] init];
    [self.htmlController requestTopicWithID:_topicID];

    NSInteger viewTag = 117;
    for (NSString *html in self.htmlController.postsContent) {
        NSString *formattedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='overflow: hidden; max-width: device-width;'>%@</div>", html];
        NSLog(@"%@", formattedHTML);
        UIWebView *content = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 1)];
        content.tag = viewTag;
        content.alpha = 0;
        content.opaque = NO;
        content.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        content.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        content.scalesPageToFit = NO;
        content.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:content];
        [content loadHTMLString:formattedHTML baseURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://www.elotrolado.net"]]; 
        NSLog(@"loading wv %i", viewTag);
        viewTag++;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark -  TableViewDelegate & DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.heightForView count]>0 ? [self.heightForView count] : 0;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self.heightForView count]>0 ? [[self.heightForView objectForKey:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.section+117]] floatValue]+20.0 : 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.section];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UIView *content = [self.view viewWithTag:(indexPath.section+117)];
        content.alpha = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:content];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size.width = 300;
    webView.frame = frame;

    [self.heightForView setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", frame.size.height] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", webView.tag]];

    if ([self.heightForView count]==[self.htmlController.postsContent count]) {
        NSLog(@"All wv loaded");
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else NSLog(@"wv %i loaded", webView.tag);
} 

@end
```

This code works with most webViews but it doesn't with large ones

Comment: can you post the related code too?

Comment: Well, I don't know what to post so I'll post the whole code of the viewController

Comment: maybe this is irrelevant, but you shouldn't use a different cell identifier for each cell. you are preventing the cells from being reused, and this may cause serious memory issues if you have lots of cells. you may want to subclass `UITableViewCell` and add a `UIWebView` to it, and then change the size there. Also are you loading ALL webviews at `viewDidLoad`? You probably want to lazily load them..

Comment: The purpose of use a unique identifier is avoid reload the webviews. The number of cells is static, always 10. Thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) (tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPaths: documentation)

> **Important** Due to an underlying implementation detail, you should not return values greater than 2009.

So my solution:

```
CGFloat height = 0;
if ([self.heightForView count]>0) {
    if (([[self.heightForView objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.section+117]] floatValue]+20.0)>2009) {
        height = 2009;
        UIWebView *content = (UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:(indexPath.section+117)];
        content.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    } else height = [[self.heightForView objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.section+117]] floatValue]+20.0;
}
return height;
```